# How can I increase the angle of an intersection?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an envelope icon in HTML/CSS but I can't seem to get this part right.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUiXs.png)

As you can see, the corners don't quite line up correctly with the diagonal lines and I don't really know how to open the angle a little more. This is what I've written :

CSS

```
.enveloppe {    
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     width: 14px; height: 11px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     margin-right: 6px;
     background: white;
    display: inline-block;
 }
.enveloppe-plie{
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 5px;
    top: 3pt;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-top: 1px solid #333333;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="enveloppe">
<div class="enveloppe-plie"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps the shape you get depends on the zoom factor of the browser - you might get better results using svg instead of div and css.

Comment: `transform: rotate(135deg), scaleX(1.2);` or something like it might help. However, it probably won't look sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `margin-left: -5px;` with `margin-left: 3px;` and it looks a bit better

Answer (score 0):

This will make a white envelope. Use this link to learn to make triangles using CSS https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

CSS

```
.envelope {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 64px;
    width: 96px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.envelope-fold1, .envelope-fold2 {
    border-right: 48px solid transparent;
    border-left: 48px solid transparent;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.envelope-fold1 {
    border-top: 48px solid black;
}
.envelope-fold2 {
    border-top: 44px solid white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="envelope">
    <div class="envelope-fold1"></div>
    <div class="envelope-fold2"></div>
</div>
```